# Xively server error when issuing <img> URL

Tags: cosm, xively

I've used Pachube/Cosm for non-commercial home sensor data collection and have been quite happy with the service.  Now I'm getting a Xively image indicating a server error when issuing this from a web page:

http://api.pachube.com/v2/feeds/9709/datastreams/0.png?width=730&height=250&colour=%23f75a22&duration=1day&legend=Temperature&title=Back%20Porch%20Temp&show_axis_labels=true&detailed_grid=true&scale=auto&min=40&max=90&timezone=Pacific%20Time%20(US%20&%20Canada)

I'm also seeing only 6 hours of my data in the charts.  After reading the statement below, I would think that I would still be able to see my data (unlimited history) and would be able to see it in the chart as described in the above URL.

What am I missing?

From the Xively blog: 
http://blog.xively.com/2013/05/15/accounts-data-devices-an-explanation/

"To reiterate, if you were a Cosm user your ‘legacy feeds’ are different to Development Devices, Production Devices and Channels, and therefore are not subject to these limitations, or having any history truncated. So, existing Cosm users have both ‘legacy feeds’ with unlimited history as well as up to 30 Channels of Production Devices with unlimited history."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a problem with URL encoding of the Time Zone parameter.

Try:

```
http://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/9709/datastreams/0.png?width=730&height=250&colour=%23f75a22&duration=1day&legend=Temperature&title=Back%20Porch%20Temp&show_axis_labels=true&detailed_grid=true&scale=auto&min=40&max=90&timezone=Pacific%20Time%20(US%20%26%20Canada)
```

Ampersand encoding: `Pacific%20Time%20(US%20&%20Canada)` versus `Pacific%20Time%20(US%20%26%20Canada)`

Comment: Amazing catch.  That fixed it.  Hard to imagine when/why it stopped working.  It's been working like this for a couple of years.  Thanks.